# apollo-client Network error if field is null

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

This particular code has been now running without issues for months, this morning, without any relevant change I can pinpoint in our setup or our code I started receiving

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Network error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object Error: Network error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:43)
    at eval (QueryManager.js:324)
    at eval (QueryManager.js:755)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (QueryManager.js:754)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (QueryManager.js:749)
    at eval (QueryManager.js:251)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4733)
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:43)
    at eval (QueryManager.js:324)
    at eval (QueryManager.js:755)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    ...
    inline.bundle.js:26 (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

This happens because of an error at Object.keys(src).forEach:

```
var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
export function merge(dest, src) {
    Object.keys(src).forEach(function (key) {
        var srcVal = src[key];
        if (!hasOwn.call(dest, key)) {
            dest[key] = srcVal;
        }
        else if (srcVal && typeof srcVal === 'object') {
            merge(dest[key], srcVal);
        }
    });
}
```

The error is:

```
"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
```

merge is called from here:

```
function executeSelectionSet(selectionSet, rootValue, execContext) {
    var fragmentMap = execContext.fragmentMap, contextValue = execContext.contextValue, variables = execContext.variableValues;
    var result = {};
    selectionSet.selections.forEach(function (selection) {
        if (!shouldInclude(selection, variables)) {
            // Skip this entirely
            return;
        }
        if (isField(selection)) {
            var fieldResult = executeField(selection, rootValue, execContext);
            var resultFieldKey = resultKeyNameFromField(selection);
            if (fieldResult !== undefined) {
                if (result[resultFieldKey] === undefined) {
                    result[resultFieldKey] = fieldResult;
                }
                else {
                    merge(result[resultFieldKey], fieldResult);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var fragment = void 0;
            if (isInlineFragment(selection)) {
                fragment = selection;
            }
            else {
                // This is a named fragment
                fragment = fragmentMap[selection.name.value];
                if (!fragment) {
                    throw new Error("No fragment named " + selection.name.value);
                }
            }
            var typeCondition = fragment.typeCondition.name.value;
            if (execContext.fragmentMatcher(rootValue, typeCondition, contextValue)) {
                var fragmentResult = executeSelectionSet(fragment.selectionSet, rootValue, execContext);
                merge(result, fragmentResult);
            }
        }
    });
    if (execContext.resultMapper) {
        return execContext.resultMapper(result, rootValue);
    }
    return result;
}
```

After I identified the field that was being parsed and the fact the it was null valued in the backend I tried to change the value and then the error moved to the next null valued field for the same node. I tried also with other queries and we have the same result.

We are using django and graphene at the backend and apollo-client at the frontend.

I would be grateful for any insight here, I am still trying to understand what has changed between 23:00 yesterday (latest time I tested the code that is now bombing and it all worked) and 1am tonight (time of the automated deployment on our dev server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar error last night and for me, I was able to track it down to a change in the [graphql-anywhere](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/tree/master/packages/graphql-anywhere) package from version 4.1.8 to 4.1.9 (updated 2 days ago).

Here is the changelog: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/graphql-anywhere/CHANGELOG.md

Adding `"graphql-anywhere": "4.1.8",` to my package.json file has solved the issue for my app.

Comment: Thanks! I will verify if this solves the problem for us too. At the moment I had to rewrite all the resolves to prevent nulls.

Comment: Looks like the new version (4.1.10) has fixed this issue: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3393

Comment: As a side effect it made me review our server side code. Which is always a good thing :D